# Transform and append string values in a list inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
dict_values = {'name':['John','Peter'], 'attach':['0001-test.jpg,0002-test.jpg','0003-test.jpg']}
```

```
name | attach
John | 0001-test.jpg,0002-test.jpg
Peter | 0003-test.jpg
```

I need to get the value before "-" and append into a list.

**Like this:**

```
name | attach
John | [0001,0002]
Peter | [0003]
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u can also use findall

```
dict_values = {'name':['John','Peter'], 
               'attach':['0001-test.jpg,0002-test.jpg','0003-test.jpg']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_values)
df['attach'] = df['attach'].str.findall("(\d+)-")
```

output,

```
    name        attach
0   John  [0001, 0002]
1  Peter        [0003]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extractall`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_values)
df['attach'] = (df.attach.str.extractall('(\d*)-')[0]
                   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
                )
```

Output:

```
    name        attach
0   John  [0001, 0002]
1  Peter        [0003]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, lets use `explode` and `agg`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_values)

df1 = df.set_index("name")["attach"].str.split(
    ",").explode().str.split("-", expand=True)[0]\
        .groupby(level=0).agg(list)

print(df1)

name
John     [0001, 0002]
Peter          [0003]
```